Did only Brahmins have gotras in the beginning and how did it spread to the other dvija castes?
Encyclopedia Brittanica says:

Gotra originally referred to the seven lineage segments of the Brahmans (priests), who trace their derivation from seven ancient seers: Atri, Bharadvaja, Bhrigu, Gotama, Kashyapa, Vasishtha, and Vishvamitra. An eighth gotra was added early on, the Agastya, named after the seer intimately linked up with the spread of Vedic Hinduism in southern India. In later times the number of gotras proliferated when a need was felt to justify Brahman descent by claiming for one’s line a Vedic seer.

How did the system evolve to what it is today and when was marriage within a gotra prohibited?
